# Android - Image Size Difference Between Using Glide and Using Only ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-glide

I have a LaunchActivity and I have a centered ImageView inside this activity. And I have a PNG with different densities. The problem is that there is a size difference between when I load my drawable png via Glide and when I use it **ONLY** by simply defining it as `android:src="@drawable/my_splash_logo"` in ImageView.

Here you can see my LaunchActivity.kt:

```
class LaunchActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var newSplashScreen: SplashScreen
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        newSplashScreen = installSplashScreen()
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch)
        setupStatusBar(R.color.transparent)
        (window.decorView.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT) as FrameLayout).foreground = null
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            val controller = window.insetsController

            if (controller != null) {
                controller.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() or WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars())
                controller.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
            }
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            val w = window // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
            w.setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION
            )
            w.setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
            )
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION)
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        }
Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.my_splash_logo)
            .into(R.id.splash_logo_imageview)
...
...
...

    }
}
```

activity_launch.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="@dimen/match_constraint"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/match_constraint">

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/splash_screen_logo_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/splash_logo_imageview"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

      <include layout="@layout/my_loading_view" />

      <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</merge>
```

I also applied my png's exact pixels like `.apply(RequestOptions().override(1110, 1144).centerCrop())` or with `.centerInside()` or `.circleCrop()` or `.fitCenter()` .

And I see the size difference when I **ONLY** use `android:src="@drawable/my_splash_logo"` in ImageView without any Glide codeline. If this line is used in ImageView without any Glide codeline, I see that the size is smaller than the result size when I used the Glide code lines.

What am I missing?

Comment: What are the sizes of the image with and without Glide?

Comment: @dominicoder as I see on layout inspector, without glide -> width=277dp height=286dp ; with glide -> width=317dp height=326dp

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without seeing the images resources. I guess when you set it as `android:src="@drawable/my_splash_logo"` it just grabs image from image resource folder which corresponds to your screen density, e.g. `xhdpi`. But when you are loading it using Glide, it might grab the largest available image, e.g. from `xxxhdpi` folder and resize it to match available space. So in case with Glide image might look larger.